# Android - Why do I need the full activity name to access my drawables and XML files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a 2nd activity in my application. Now I need to add `com.example.avenger` every time I need to do something like `val dialogImageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.dialog_imageview) as ImageView`

Comment: Where are you having to add it? If it is to `R.id.dialog_imageview`, you do not have an `import` statement for your `R` class in your new file.

Comment: Thank you! I importing something else and that's why it didn't work. Can you add what you wrote as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `R` itself is being recognized, but not specific resources of yours, usually that means that you have an `import` for somebody else's `R` class. For example, you might have an `import` of `R` from a library, because you are also referring to some resources from that library.

In the end, only one can be used via the `R` shorthand and the `import`. If you are using Java, pick whichever `R` you are more likely to use and `import` that one, then fully-qualify references to the other. If you are using Kotlin, you can rename imports, so you could have one as `R` and one as `RMaterial` (if, for example, the `R` you are colliding with is from the Material Components for Android library).